# Showing that $a \times [a \times [a \times (a \times b)]]=x^4 b$ where $x = \| a \|$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R^3$ be orthogonal vectors and set $x=\| a \|$.
Show that: $a \times [a \times [a \times (a \times b)]]=x^4 b$

So I'm currently here and don't know where to go next:

$a \times (a \times b) = (a \cdot a)b-(a \cdot b)a$

=$(a \cdot a)b - 0$ as $a$,$b$ is orthogonal the dot product = 0

= $(a \cdot a) b$

Left with : $a\times[a\times[(a \cdot a) b]]=x^4b$

Comment: What does it mean to set $a$, which is a vector, equal to the norm of $x$, which is undefined?

Comment: OP: You probably mean $\|a\| = x$, rather than $a = \|x\|$.

Comment: Your post still doesn't make sense.  As @BrianTung indicates, you probably meant $x = \lVert a\rVert$.  But don't write $x = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$; this is abusing $x$.  Finally, is $a^2b$ meant to be $x^2b$?

Comment: Be careful when messing about with dot products. $a^2 b$ is **not** the same thing as $(a \cdot a)b$. The latter is a scalar multiple of $b$, the former is not even defined.

Comment: OP: See if you can figure out what $a \times (a \times b)$ is, in terms of $b$ and $x$.  ETA: Be careful and *slow down* — your numerous errors, trivial as they may be individually, are a sign you are rushing through the problem and not being careful.  That can be quite fatal in mathematics (figuratively speaking, of course!).

Comment: Without loss of generality assume $\,a=(0,0,1)\,$ and $b=(1,0,0).$

Comment: (We're not having issues understanding---we are taking issue with the problem, as written in the body, being incorrect. We're not suggesting you clarify the problem because *we* need to understand it; it's not our problem to solve.)

Comment: @LSpice I added a screenshot of the problem as there's was some difficulty writing it here. $a^2b$ is not meant to be $x^2b$ the added set a=∥x∥ is for extra difficulty I guess but as Brian and prets indicated I am completely lost in this problem xD

Comment: @prets I know, I appreciate all the indicators so far! I wrote it as best as I could

Comment: @BrianTung Thank you, I'll try to head down the path of simply taking cross products rather than changing to some sort of dot product manipulation. I assumed since the question involves orthogonal vectors the trick would involve the dot product of two orthogonal vectors equaling 0.

Comment: Despite what you say, it is essentially equivalent to $\|a\| = x$; the only difference is that the screenshotted problem shows vectors in bold, like $\mathbf{a}$, and then the normal italic form $a$ is the magnitude.

Comment: @BrianTung My confusion, will change that now =) thank you

Comment: @yay I cleaned up the LaTeX and the picture transcription some. If something no longer agrees with your intention, feel free to change it accordingly.

Comment: @prets Thanks a lot =) I need to get more proficient with this for sure

Comment: Your triple product expansion is incorrect: It is $a \times (a \times b) = a(a \cdot b)-b(a \cdot a) = -x^2b$.  You have the subtraction going the other way.  In this case, it doesn't affect the answer for the original problem, but that's not guaranteed to be true.

Comment: @Somos: I don't think $a$ and $b$ are known to be unit vectors.

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, of course, but both sides scale the same with length of $a$ and $b$ so, WLOG you can assume them to be unit vectors. Also, WLOG you can assume $a$ and $b$ to be any two orthogonal unit vectors, so pick two specific orthogonal vectors where it is easy to see what happens.

Comment: @Somos: Oh, I agree that the difference is minor to someone who's comfortable manipulating things in this way.  But this is evidently early in the OP's learning of cross products, so they may not get what they're doing if they go that route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $x=\|a\|$, you can do the following. First, as you proved:
$a\times (a\times b)=-x^2b$ (there is a slight misprint in the question). Then denote $b_1=a\times (a\times b)$, it is also orthogonal to $a$, so applying what you have to $b_1$, you get that your vector is $a\times (a\times b_1)=-x^2b_1=(-x^2)(-x^2)b=x^4b$.

Comment: Tip: You get better kerning on the norm symbol by using `\|` instead of `||`.

Comment: OK. I do not know what kerning is but I have fixed it.

Comment: (It's printing world fancy speak for "distance between things"! @markvs)

Comment: "Kerning" refers to the spacing between characters (or parts of characters, in this case—an abuse of notation, but it gets the point across).

Comment: Better kerning still is `\lVert\rVert`, which allows it to distinguish mathclose from mathopen.

Comment: OK. The kerning seems to be good now.

Comment: @LSpice: That is already too complicated for me.

Comment: Best beware, lest we turn into tex.SE... :)

Comment: Thanks for this, just currently trying to get my head around it and get a solution that makes sense with me given this =)

Comment: Incidentally, on a mathematical point, OP has the triple product expansion backwards: It is $a \times (a \times b) = a(a \cdot b)-b(a \cdot a) = -x^2b$.  It doesn't happen to matter in this case, but you should probably fix that.

Comment: @BrianTung: This last comment is for whom? I just used what OP wrote.  But it does not matter indeed  since $(-x^2)(-x^2)=x^4$.

Comment: @markvs: Yes, I understand you merely duplicated the OP's error—but since it *is* an error, I think it is worth fixing it in your answer.

Comment: @LSpice: Does that actually produce better kerning, or is it just better LaTeX style?  (Not that I'm against the latter, but that's a few extra keystrokes to remember.)

Comment: @BrianTung, compare, for example, $\|-b\|$ `\|-b\|` to $\lVert-b\rVert$ `\lVert-b\rVert`.

Comment: @BrianTung And if you do this frequently, make use of `mathtools`'s `\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}` (or similar), so you can just fo `\norm{-b}`. Also automatically makes a `\norm*` for automatic sizing, and allows for `\norm[Big]` etc. for manual sizing.

Comment: `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` is awesome (and, yes, `\norm` and `\abs` make their way into almost every document I write …).

Comment: (I even go so far as to make them fill in automatic $\cdot$ for placeholders so I can do `\abs{}` for $| {\,\cdot\,} |$ etc., and likewise make ones that take two arguments for inner products and the like. And then I get all lost on here when I have to manually type the delimiters like a chump!)

Comment: @prets (and LSpice, but I don't think I can tag multiple people here): Thanks for the tips!  I'll check that out for my LaTeX papers.

Comment: Upvoted with the correction. :-)